# Delete multiple dynamically named cookies in Openresty Lua

Tags: cookies, lua, openresty

Below code works fine in Openresty lua

```
ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = {
   'test1=; expires=Thu, Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 UTC; domain=test.com;',
   'test2=; expires=Thu, Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 UTC; domain=test.com;'
}
```

though when trying to make the cookie names dynamic, it doesn't work:

```
local cookies = {}
local args = {'test1', 'test2'}

for i=1, #args do
  cookies[i] = args[i] .. '=; expires=Thu, Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 UTC; domain=test.com;'
end

ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = cookies
```

have even tried using table.insert:

```
local cookies = {}
local args = {'test1', 'test2'}

for i=1, #args do
  table.insert(cookies, args[i] .. '=; expires=Thu, Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 UTC; domain=test.com;')
end

ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = cookies
```

Issue seems with the assignment of variable to `ngx.header["Set-Cookie"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ngx.header.set_cookie` instead of `ngx.header["Set-Cookie"]` works. The following code works now:

```
local cookies = {}
local args = {'test1', 'test2'}

for i=1, #args do
  cookies[i] = args[i] .. '=; expires=Thu, Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 UTC; domain=test.com;'
end

ngx.header.set_cookie = cookies
```